# Cheapest train from Milan to Monaco

Tags: budget, trains, monaco, milan

How much does the cheapest train from Milan to Monaco (Ventimiglia) cost?

Comment: on http://www.voyages-sncf.com I found they cost 37 to 50 euros (standard adult price). But who knows, maybe you can find a better deal. By the way, Ventimiglia and Monaco are not the same station, tickets are 10 euros cheaper to Ventimiglia (but most trains are through Ventimiglia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The possible train solutions can be found in the [Trenitalia site](http://www.trenitalia.com/trenitalia.html).

Currently the cheapest train from Milan to Ventimiglia is the regional train. It takes almost five hours and costs 22.25 euros.

It is possible, anyway, to find some good offers for faster trains at a price lower than the one of the regional train. These discounted seats have some limitations, for example you won't be able to change your reservation without paying an extra fee.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the game, but if it can help somene...

You can find rails tickets from Milano to Monaco on [Thello](https://www.thello.com/)

In 2017, price is 15€ if you book your ticket 1 month (or more) in advance.
But if you need it for tomorrow, the cost may go up to 42€.

There are 3 trains per day, usually 7AM, 11AM and 3PM. The journey takes approximatively 4h30.

Comment: great info!  where do you change on that journey?

Comment: No change - it's direct. The train goes from Milano (Italy) to Marseille (France) and stops in a lots of cities like Genoa, Monaco, Nice, Antibes etc... See the full list on their website

Comment: Awesome, cool.  I've only been on it around MC.  Cheers